# Limit dynamically added columns to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please take a look at this **[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jqVxu/51/)**. I'm adding new columns using AJAX on click. Is there a way to count the columns of the table and limit the number of new columns to 6? Could anyone give me suggestions?

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
var ajaxfunction = function(){
        $('.area').on("click","button", function(){
        var source = $(this).data('feed');

        $.ajax({
    url: source,
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {         
         var title = item.title,
          year = item.year, 
          job = item.Job,
          education = item.Education,
          background = item.Background,
          ingredient = item.Ingredient;
         $('#header').after('<th>'+title+'</th>')
         $('#ingredient').after('<td>'+ingredient+'</td>')
         $('#year').after('<td>'+year+'</td>')
         $('#background').after('<td>'+background+'</td>')
         $('#education').after('<td>'+education+'</td>')
         $('#job').after('<td>'+job+'</td>')

        });
        $('#toptable').stickyTableHeaders(); //Fixed Header Plugin
     },
    });


  });

 }
ajaxfunction();


});
```

HTML

```
<div class="area">
    <button>Class B</button>
    <button>Class C</button>
    <button>Class D</button>

</div>

<table id="toptable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th id="header" style="visibility:hidden">-</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td id="ingredient">Ingredient</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="year">Year</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="background">Background</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="education">Education</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td id="job">Job</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Column Count (If you start using colspans this will need to change to reflect that):

`var colcount = $("#toptable").find("tr:first th").length;` or

`var colcount = $("tr:first th", "#toptable").length;` or

`var colcount = $("#toptable tr:first th").length;`

Limit the number of columns (tested and working):

```
$('.area').on("click","button", function(){
      var colspan = $("#toptable tr:first th").length;
        alert("Current number of Columns = " + colspan);
        if(colspan > 6)
        {
            alert("Too Many Columns");
            return false;
        }
    var source = $(this).data('feed');
    //the rest of your code
});
```

See [this working Fiddle](http://sfiddle.net/jqVxu/62/)

**NOTE:** Because you are adding columns on an Ajax Success result, the column count is only true *at the time of the `click` event*. This means that the column count could be more once the Ajax Response arrives. You need to either cancel the request if there is an Ajax call in progress, or redesign so that you're not making so many HTTP calls (which is bad practice anyway, something like 68% of all performance improvements on the web are found in reducing HTTP calls.)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get it to work [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqVxu/57/) correct one

Comment: I just read some other threads about aborting ajax request. This is what I've changed. Not sure if it has any effect though. I can't really see the difference. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqVxu/68/)

Comment: It will only make a difference if the user clicks a button more than once: eg. User clicks, there are 5 columns, Ajax call goes ahead, user clicks again, ajax call hasnt finished yet, there are still 5 columns so another ajax call goes ahead, when both calls return there are 7 columns because each call got through and returned 1 column.